# templateUrl not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

So for some reason the HTML page i'm trying to load with templateUrl is not showing up. The files are all in the same directory, console shows no error, it just doesn't load the page elements i'm trying to add. My directive is as simple as:

```
.directive('tagTeste',function(){
    return{
        templateUrl: 'templateUrl.html'
    };
});
```

My template html i'm trying to load:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="teste">
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" width="500" height="150">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>Nome</td>
         <td>Telefone</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="pessoa in pessoas">
          <td>{{pessoa.nome}}</td>
          <td>{{pessoa.telefone}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<form>
  <p> Nome: <input type="text" ng-model="nomenovo" required> </p>
  <p> Telefone: <input type="number" ng-model="numeronovo" required> </p>
  <input type="button" ng-click="add()">
</form>
<body>
</html>
```

My index page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="teste">
  <head>
    <h1 align="center">Table teste</h1>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Teste</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="repeaterdirective.js"></script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="templateUrl.html">
  </head>
  <div ng-controller="index" align="center">
  <body>
    <div tag-teste></div>
  </body>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the closing `</div>` after `</body>` in your index page just a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateUrl.html">` from index.

And clear a bit `templateUrl.html`. Tags as `<html>` and `<body>` are already contained in index.

Take a look at [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NeowC6npUfYzUbmOgyAU?p=preview).

Updated after comment:

Change index as:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="teste">
  <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Teste</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="index" align="center">
      <h1 align="center">Table teste</h1>
      <div tag-teste></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Now it gives me the error: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. Which i guess it's cause i'm not using a web server

Comment: That's why i was trying to load the templateUrl page with the script tag.

Comment: Can you please create a demo of this problem in fiddle or plunker to take a look? Or try to change your code as in plunker just posted, where template of the directive is being loaded without cross-origin errors.

Comment: Here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/e24Y7C9rjsKXkt0PTyJx?p=preview

Comment: Updated my answer. Change a little the index.html

Comment: In plunker I can see it is working [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/fIy35UpURqrfGxkqCHVq?p=preview).

Comment: It is definitely working in the last plunker you provided but i got the same code and can't run it cause of the error i mentioned (i assume plunker uses its own web server)

Comment: Do you have node installed on your system? What OS are you using?

Comment: I do have node and i'm using ubuntu 16.0.4

Comment: Did you install `http-server`? (`sudo npm install http-server -g`) If you do, just go to the working folder (where `index.html` lives) in terminal, and run `http-server`.

Comment: "Starting up http-server, serving C:\home\joao\Desktop\projetosAtom\Testedirectives\index.html" but when i try to open the page on the browser i get a 404, have tried "C:\home\joao\Desktop\projetosAtom\Testedirectives\" as path too

Comment: I tried both http://localhost:8080 and  http://localhost:8080/index.html

Comment: When you run `http-server` it says something like `Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://10.0.75.1:8080
  http://192.168.56.1:8080
  http://10.0.3.22:8080
  http://127.0.0.1:8080`. Can you verify that port 8080 is being used?

Comment: Starting up http-server, serving C:\home\joao\Desktop\projetosAtom\Testedirectives\
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://192.168.100.24:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server

Comment: Can you try `http://localhost:8080/#/` or `http://localhost:8080/#/index`?

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer and will start testing this application on firefox (it worked properly there running on local files), thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the true answer is a combination of both the answers. Unfortunately, I can't help you without seeing your screen.. I would suggest you to spend some time to automate your development process, setting up node modules packages, gulp tasks etc. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

If you use `templateUrl` while loading your file in Chrome browser with the `file:///`, protocol you will always get this error.

On the other hand Mozilla Firefox will allow it, so will Microsoft Edge.

The other solution is to serve your pages from an HTTP server.

An easy one to use is [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Thanks for posting.

Comment: How should I proceed with this? I installed http-server and as a beginner don't know how to start the server with my index file.

Comment: To start the server you simply  use the command `http-server` followed by the absolute path to your folder, for example `http-server c:\myFolder `. This will start the server on port 8080, so just open a browser to `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: I've tried running http-server C:\home\joao\Desktop\projetosAtom\Testedirectives\
but nothing happens

Comment: It says now the page wasn't found

Comment: If your page is not named `index.html` it will not be loaded automatically. Then add the file name at the end of the path `http-server C:\home\joao\Desktop\projetosAtom\Testedirectives\file.html`

Comment: Sorry, just start your server with `http-server C:\home\joao\Desktop\projetosAtom\Testedirectives\ `, then in your browser add the file name at the end of the URL in the address bar.